# The meaning: I don't think he's changed in thirty years

Tags: present-perfect

My textbook says this use of the present perfect has the meaning of the present perfect continuous, as there is an indication of the period (in thirty years).

It also says that *changed* here can't have terminative meaning, only durative.

But there is a doubt I understand the textbook in the right way.

So what's the meaning?

Is it that he *never changed during all those years*?

Comment: Well, *I don't think he's been changing in thirty years* makes little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Past: He never changed in thirty years. - past time period
(for example 1970-2000)

Present  Perfect : He hasn't changed in thirty years. (1986 - 2016)
(starting in the past, up to today)

Present Perfect Continuous is for an action he HAS been doing for thirty years. Present Perfect is for an action that HASN'T happened in thirty years.

Comment: I understand what Past Simple would mean. 

I also understand 'He hasn't changed' has the Present Perfect form. 

My question is whether the Present Perfect in this case has meaning of the Present Perfect Continuous. 

And if not, if it has the meaning of genuine Present Perfect, how can it coexist with indication of period in one sentence?

Comment: @PavelTarouts See edited answer.

Comment: @PavelTarouts It's perfectly acceptable to use the present perfect with temporal expressions which include the present.

Comment: Thank you guys. So it's the Present Perfect proper as my textbook calls it (as opposed to the Present Perfect II, that has the meaning of the Present Perfect Continuous, like 'I've slept it this bed since I was a child').

Comment: @PavelTarouts or: I've been sleeping in this bed since I was a child. But: I haven't slept in this bed since I was a child.

Comment: @CathyGartaganis Yes "I've been sleeping" can be used to express the idea, but can't "I've slept" be used (at least in some cases) to express the same?

Comment: I'm asking because the textbook tells this:
2) Present Perfect II serves to express an action which began
before the moment of speaking and continues into it or up to it.
This grammatical meaning is mainly expressed by the Present Perfect Continuous. However, the Present Perfect Non-Continuous is found in the following cases:
...
b) With some dynamic verbs of durative meaning the Present
Perfect is sometimes used instead of the Present Perfect Continuous with little difference in meaning.

Comment: e.g.
"It's a pretty room, isn't it?" "I've slept in it for fifteen
years."
"I'm glad to meet you," he said. "I've waited a long while and
began to be afraid I'd not have the opportunity."
He's looked after Miss Gregg for many years now.

The examples I believe are from books. 

Is there a problem with the textbook? Is it too old, too British, or maybe too literary?

Comment: @PavelTarouts The English language constantly changes. Until recently it was fairly common to use the simple PrPf for these "continuative" perfects; but the last 50 or 100 years have seen a steady increase in use of the progressive PrPf, so the simple version is now rather formal or literary. They mean the same thing.

Comment: @PavelTarouts Some verbs don't take continuous tenses anyway, so, I've believed in this theory all my life. Other verbs go both ways: I've lived / I've been living here for five years. Longer periods of time are usually used with simple tenses: I've lived here all my life. It's also possible to say: I've slept in this bed for thirty years. (a long time period)

Comment: Thank you guys once more, your comments have helped me a lot